# SQL - If one amount null sum the other column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
 Lot | Major | Amt | overrideamt
 100   7002    1000    NULL
 100   7005    2000    500
 100   7006     500   3000
```

I need to sum the AMT column unless there is an amount in the overrideamt column. All I need is the sum total. 
So major code

```
7002 = 1000
7005 = 500
7006 = 3000
Total = 4500
```

Comment: How did you try to do it? What is your question?

Comment: I guess I didn't explain my question well. I did get 2 different answers and both work for what I was doing. At the end of the day I was making it too hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN overrideamt IS NULL THEN Amt ELSE overrideamt) AS Total
FROM tablename
```

Or [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) if you are using SQL Server 2012+:

```
SELECT
  SUM(IIF(overrideamt IS NULL, Amt,overrideamt)) AS Total
FROM tablename
```

[***demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b40ff/1)

This will give you:

```
| Total |
|-------|
|  4500 |
```

Comment: case when bool then x else y ***end***
just in case somebody passed by

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(overrideamt, Amt)) AS Total FROM tablename
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more explanation how and why your query works as an answer?  Looking for details around your COALESCE usage

Comment: COALESCE will pick the first value that is not null. For example, COALESCE(null, null, Amt, overrideamt, null), this will use Amt.

Comment: Please put this in the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) function, which is a shortcut for CASE and helpful to manage **nulls**

```
declare @tmp table(a int, b int)
insert into @tmp
select 1,null union
select 2,null union
select 3,null union
select 4,4 

select sum(coalesce(b,a)) from @tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(overrideamt,Amt)) AS Total
FROM YourTable
```

You can also use `ISNULL()`, but `COALESCE()` allow more that two values (you can use it for three or more columns like `COALESCE(Column1,Column2,Column3)`).

Comment: This works well. I was making it too hard. Quite simple.